# Dificuldade com dois segmento de uri

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

Estão tentando criar a url, onde o primeiro segmento é o usuario e o segundo é o arquivo dele, ex: http://www.exemplo.com/joao/bola

Controller

```
public function user() {

    $user_url = $this->uri->segment(1);

}
```

^ Esse retornaria o perfil com todos os arquivo: http://www.exemplo.com/joao

```
public function arquivo() {

    $arquivo_url = $this->uri->segment(2);

}
```

^ Esse o arquivo especifico: http://www.exemplo.com/joao/bola

Routes

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/user/$1';
$route['??'] = 'home/arquivo/$1';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já conseguir a solução seria algo como

```
$route['([^/]+)'] = 'home/user/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home/arquivo/$1';
```